# Using value of an instance as a readonly for all other classes

Tags: c#

I'm storing a value coming from a database in instance variable in LoadData Class

```
public class LoadData
{
    public  string _projectName;

    public void GetProjectName()
    {
         //Retrieving data from db

        _projectName= dt.Rows[0]["projectname"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this string value as a readonly each time a different ViewModel get's called later on.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Your question is far from clear. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the relationship between `LoadData` and the rest of the code, along with a detailed description of how exactly you mean to "use this string value as a readonly" (i.e. what does that even mean?)

Comment: Have ya *tried* making it static?  Do you know what static is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark the value as static, which allows anything to access it. You can also apply the `readonly` keyword to prevent the value from being overwritten once you have assigned it the initial value from the database.

```
public class LoadData
{
    public static readonly  string _projectName;

    public void GetProjectName()
    {
         //Retrieving data from db
        _projectName= dt.Rows[0]["projectname"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I would wrap this in a property though, instead of exposing a field like you are.

```
public class LoadData
{
    private static readonly  string _projectName;
    public string ProjectName
    {
        get { return LoadData._projectName; }
    }

    public void GetProjectName()
    {
         //Retrieving data from db
        _projectName= dt.Rows[0]["projectname"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This allows you to keep the static member private so that nothing sees it. Now everytime you create a new `LoadData` instance, you can access `ProjectName` and be given the value you fetched the first time.

I personally use static fields to cache data; I try to not rely on static fields as public members of a class though. In this case, since it is acting as a cache, it is better to just expose it as an instance property that returns the readonly static cache. Making it static ensures the value is shared across every instance of the `LoadData` class.